Combining style authoryear with style numeric in BibLaTeX
This is kind of a reverse to Combining style numeric with style authoryear in BibLaTeX.
I want to mostly use the author-year citation style within text; However in certain low-space environments such as tables, figures and footnotes I want to be able to resort to numeric citation style.
So basically how can one setup biblatex such that:

We have at least 3 useful citation commands:

\textcite ⇝ <author> (<year>)
\parencite ⇝ (<author>, <year>)
\labelcite ⇝ [<label>]


The bibliography follows author-year style, sorting=nyt, but with added numeric labels as in Combining style numeric with style authoryear in BibLaTeX



We can use the idea from Combining style numeric with style authoryear in BibLaTeX, but build everything onto style=authoryear, and just transplant numeric.cbx's \cite definition into our preamble under a new name.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

\newbibmacro*{numcite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\numcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{numcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{wilde,geer,worman}

\parencite{wilde,geer,worman}

\numcite{wilde,geer,worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



Firstly, try to 'borrow' or imitate some macros from the author-year style.
\newbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
        {}
        {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

This can be relatively simple, as long as you use a citation style that is founded upon the author-year system.
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    sorting=nyt,
    citestyle=numeric,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
]{biblatex}

At this point, it's possible to create a macro to control a citation command that prints an author-year reference enclosed in parentheses.
\newbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
    \iffieldundef{label}
        {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
        {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{label}}}}
\newbibmacro*{cite:author}{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}

\newbibmacro*{citeauthoryear}{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}%
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
            {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
                \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
            {\usebibmacro{cite:author}}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

Now, everything is ready for a new citation command: the \authoryearparen one.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\authoryearparen}[\mkbibparens]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{citeauthoryear}}%
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

To obtain a \textcite citation command in the author-year style, the quickest method is to 'stole' it from the numeric style by customising it main macro: the textcite one. Here, we have to replace the cite macro, the one that prints the label within parentheses, with the cite:labeldate+extradate macro.
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
    \ifnameundef{labelname}%
        {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
        {\printnames{labelname}}%
        \setunit*{\printdelim{namelabeldelim}}%
        \printtext{\bibopenbracket}\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
        \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
    \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}%
    {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
    {}%
    \textcitedelim}}

Consequently, the \textcite citation command is now exclusively for the author-year style, whereas the \cite command remains for the numeric style. Additionally, a new citation command, the \authoryearparens one, is introduced. If you really need a \textcite command, maybe in rare circumstances such as ‘certain low-space environments’, my suggestion is to cite two times: the first one with the \citeauthor{entrykey} citation command and the second one, after a space and within round parens, the \cite{entrykey}:
as dimonstrated by \citeauthor{entrykey} (\cite{entrykey}).

Obviously, this approach is suitable if you don't require a systematic solution for these ‘certain low-space environments’ and are certain that you won't need to perform complex tasks there. To conclude, this final suggestion is particularly relevant if you plan to rely solely on the \cite{entry key} command for citations in these cases.
